# What are some great and useful resources for an Isometric game built on the XNA Framework?

Tags: xna, c#, animation, assets, isometric

I'm currently working on an isometric game using the Microsoft XNA Framework. I'm looking of resources that would be of use for making this a successful project, such as isometric engines, physics engines, sprite engines(for isometric games), event handlers for ...

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The isometric projection is not so much relevant for the underlying tools you choose, it's just the way (angle, no perspective distortion) you look at things, but that doesn't change the underlying principles of how things behave. That means you don't need to particularly search for isometric tools.

The physics for instance is the same, no matter how you look at it. The math of a car crash does not change, whether you look at it from the left or from the right, it does not depend on the observer. The same is true for a bouncing ball, it does not care if you watch it from the left or from top, it will bounce the same way always.

If you have particular doubts about how to implement such things in terms of isometric projections, please tell us an example and we can go into details :)

Answer (score 3):

I followed the tile engine tutorials on this site: [xnaresources.com](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=TUTORIALS). The tile engine tutorial starts out as a regular square tile map but on Part Four they convert it to isometric. They cover drawing, tile depth, tile picking (i.e. "What tile did I click on?"), and adding a controllable character.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an engine, but [I made a fork](https://bitbucket.org/layoric/tiledlib) of [Nick Gravelyn's TiledLib](https://bitbucket.org/nickgravelyn/tiledlib) project that shows an example of that library rendering an isometric Tiled map. Not perfect, (probably buggy) but might help you start and if you have any problems, post a bug and I'll see if I can help out.

HTH